# Power Automate Flow to send a Customer Voice survey

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector, ms-forms

I have created a Power Automate Flow to send a survey to the Contact's Email when an opportunity is modified.

So, I have used 'Send a Survey'(Customer Voice) action to send a survey to the retrieved Email from Contact Entity.

In, 'Send a Survey' action,I have to choose the created Customer Voice Project(Survey) from the Environment.

Now, I want to migrate the Power Automate Flow from the source Environment to the destination Environment.

I tried by adding Flow to the Solution and imported in the Destination Environment.

**After importing, the Flow is still connected to the Customer Voice Project from the old Environment.**

1.Can anyone help me how can I make the Power Automate Flow to be configured to Customer Voice Project in the new Environment while exporting?

2.I have copied the Customer Voice Project from Source to Destination Environment as shown in the below URL.
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-voice/manage-projects](https://stackoverflow.com)
But the configured Power Automate Flow is not copied to the Destination Environment.

Comment: Just change the connected project inside of the power automate action.